# Issues when using Bootstrap 3 Modal with sticky footer in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer, bootstrap-modal

My site uses the "sticky footer" method described at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/.

I have noticed a couple of issues when using a Bootstrap 3 Modal. One, right when the modal is displayed the scroll position is reset to the top. Two, after the modal is closed any content below the fold is no longer "active" - buttons and links do not work.

My guess is that the modal backdrop is continuing to "cover" the content?

I've tried with setting the modal backdrop to "false" or "static" per the data attribute to no avail.

So far this seems to only be an issue in IE, not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works but it seems a bit hackish.

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $("html, body").css("height", "100%");
});

$(document).on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $("html, body").css("height", "inherit"); 
}
```

Of course this will "un-stick" the footer if visible. Any other ideas?